# Polyurethane application flop

Tags: finish

I applied polyurethane on my really nice formal table. I did not wait 24hours before resanding. I used steel wool the wipe and there are streaks, bumps, and is now looks terrible. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Use 220G sandpaper to thoroughly sand the top, dust the top and also wipe lightly with a tack rag. Then apply a very thin coat of poly over the top. Do what you can to keep the dust from settling on it. If possible support a piece of poly over the top that will block the dust form dropping in the finish. Allow no drafts in the same room

Comment: Just a note -- use a flat sanding block with the sandpaper... And if your finish was water based, steel wool isn't ideal.